# UIViewControllers problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Hi there and thank you in advice for your help. I have a really strange problem while working with ViewControllers in Xcode4. First of all I have to say that I'm not using storyboards and I prefer to create any UI element programmatically. So I've set a UIButton and I want that, when pressed, it brings me to a new view controller. This is the code I'm using for a button:

```
-(void)settingsAndExportHandle:(UIButton *)buttonSender {
SettingsViewController* settingView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
settingView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:settingView animated:YES];
```

}

This buttons is initialized and allocated in the viewDidLoad method of the RootViewController. I want to switch to the other view controller (in this case SettingsViewController) when I press the button.

The strange thing is that when I press the button, the animation that flips the controllers goes well, but when it finishes I obtain the EXACT same things that I had on the RootViewControllers (same custom views, same buttons, same all!). The question is: what I'm missing?? I have to say that I use ARC (automatic reference counting) so I can't release or dealloc the views and buttons I've created on my RootViewController.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Offtopic: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated. Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Comment: I fixed this one! You know what was the problem? The new UIViewController class that I had created strangely had this lines of code in the header file:

`@interface SettingsViewController : ViewController

@end`

Unfortunately ViewController is the name of my Root View Controller. I changed that line to UIViewController (that is to say that the new view controller, named SettingsViewController, will be a sublass NOT of my own ViewController (my root controller in this case), but will be a subclass of UIViewController (like it was meant to be)).

Thank you all! Solved!

Comment: This is unbelievable +1!

Answer (score 0):

Pushing and and modally presenting view controllers does *not* deallocate the view controller that presented them. It simply adds the additional view controller to the stack. You'll need to implement a callback method so that when the user hits the button to flip back to root view controller, your settings view controller lets the root view controller know what's about to happen so you can call a method you've written to reset the interface back to whatever state you need it at. You may also be able to use `viewWillAppear:` but that's a little messy.

*However*, according to the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, the user expects that when they push a view controller or modally present it, the view controller they were on will save state and be exactly the way they left it when they came back. It's disconcerting and annoying when state is not preserved while in a navigation controller context. It is **especially** annoying when it's modally presented.

Think about this - A user is in a hypothetical Mail app. They start typing out an email and set a font size and a color. They tap on the add attachment button, which brings up a modal view controller that allows them to select a picture. They select the picture and the modal view is dismissed, and in your implementation, the mail composing interface would have reset and the email content would be gone or at the very least the selected font size and color would be back to the default. That's not a good experience.